# How to prevent X11 forwarding?

Tags: xorg

How to prevent X11 forwarding in a local desktop setup? How to make sure that only the local monitor can display X11?

Comment: Are you referring to X11 forwarding over SSH? if so, that's controlled by the `X11Forwarding` setting in the server's sshd_config

Comment: Thanks. But the services in my machine does not even include sshd (that I know of, using service status-all). Can the X11 be somehow be viewed remotely without (an obvious) ssh?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can prevent this by adding the following lines

- X11Forwarding no
- X11UseForwarding no

to the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (if not there, but if there just uncomment them) configuration file and restarting the daemon:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

`xhost` is the X11 tool for controlling access to the local X server. `man xhost`